# Have rigid body animation only rotate and not translate

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am about to create an Animation of a cloth-hanger, which is meant to become a »real« one, because it should be a rigid body in a physic simulation. The cloth-hanger should hang a real one does and its behaviour should come relatively close to reality. Please see the image below, to get a better idea of the idea behind it.

[image: cloth-hanger]

Here are some details of the model:

[image]
[image]

**Question:**

I am trying to join the hook and the bar in such a way that the bar can rotate around the hook, but not translate. So my first question is: How can I establish such a joint?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2074/599. The application is a little different, but the method should be the same.

Comment: It would help if the diagrams had some notes in them to label the parts which are being discussed, and maybe some arrows to show desired axis of motion for various parts.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks a lot, that seems to do the trick!