# partial fracturing

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I’ve been looking on the internet but have not found any answers.

How to make an object not fall apart entirely when being hit by another object. So that it can still move around with the pieces, that where left from the first impact, saving its fractured form. more exactly to make so that every piece of an object has some value of force needed to detach it from others. How do you do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're searching for *Constraints*. Related: [Rigid body animation with constraints and relationships](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/rigid-body-animation-with-constraints-and-relationships)

Comment: Or you could just change the rigid body's that should stay in place to passive (constrains wörk but they can be a bit finicky)